# Questions about uncountable orthonormal bases in Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I am currently reading the chapter on Hilbert spaces in the book *Functional Analysis* by *Peter D. Lax* and I am confused about whether the orthonormal sets being alluded to are uncountable or not.

Specifically he states the following theorem

> **Theorem 9.** Every Hilbert space contains an orthonormal basis.

The proof of this theorem never refers to whether the set obtained via an application of Zorn's lemma is countable or not. He then goes on to state that:

> Suppose that $H$ is a separable Hilbert space; that is, it contains a denumerable set of points that is dense. In this case every orthogonal basis is denumerable, and the basis elements can be constructed without appealing to transcendental arguments such as Zorn's lemma...

so i assume that the theorem is valid for any Hilbert space. But then if $\{x_j\}$ is some orthonormal set in a Hilbert space then is it true, as is claimed in the book, that $\overline{\mathrm{span }\{x_j\}} = S$ where $S$ is the set of points
\begin{align*}
x = \sum (x,x_j)x_j,\quad \sum |(x,x_j)|^2<\infty.
\end{align*}
Are we to consider this as a transfinite sum?

Could we go about proving this in the following way:

Suppose that $\{x_j\}$ is uncountable and let $y\in \overline{\mathrm{span}\{x_j\}}$ then we could find a sequence $\{y_n\}$ together with an increasing sequence of finite index sets $\{F_n\}$ and scalars $\{c_{n,j}\}$ such that

$$y_n = \sum_{j\in F_n}c_{n,j}x_j$$

and $\|y_n-y\|\rightarrow 0$. By Pythagoras

$$\|y-y_n\|\geq \|y-\sum_{j\in F_n}(y,x_j)x_j\|$$

and therefore $\sum_{j\in F_n}(y,x_j)x_j\rightarrow y$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. By Bessel's inequality we have for finite index sets $F$

$$\sum_{j\in F}|(y,x_j)|^2\leq \|y\|^2$$

and therefore

$$\sum |(y,x_j)|^2 = \sup_{F\text{ is finite}}\sum_{j\in F}|(y,(x_j))|^2\leq \|y\|^2$$

which implies that $y\in S$. But how is the sum $\sum(y,x_j)x_j$ defined? It is transfinite but not positive?

---

As Asaf Karagila stated in the comments the fact that $\sum |(y,x_j)|^2<\infty$ implies that at most countably many $(y,x_j)$ are nonzero.

Say that $G$ is a countable set which contains all indices $j$ such that $(y,x_j)\neq 0$ and let $G_n$ be some sequence of finite indices such that $\cup G_n = G$. We want to show that

$$\lim_n \sum_{G_n}(y,x_j)x_j = y.$$

Note that we can choose $G_n$ such that $F_n\setminus G_n$ only contains indices $j$ with the property that $(y,x_j) = 0$ then

$$\|y-y_n\|\geq \|y-\sum_{G_n}(y,x_j)x_j\|$$

which proves the result.

Comment: For a sum of positive real numbers to be finite there can only be countably many of them. So your requirement on $\sum|(x,x_j)|^2$ is already limiting you back to "standard" series representations.

Comment: Thank you I will edit my question

Comment: A Hilbert space is separable iff it has a ONB of countable or less cardinality. There exist non-separable Hilbert spaces, or Hilbert spaces with uncountable ONBs. Indeed the cardinality of an ONB in a Hilbert space is an important invariant, if $H$ has two ONB $\{x_i\}$ and $\{y_j\}$ then both must have the same cardinality. Further, two Hilbert spaces are unitarily isomorphic iff they have ONBs of the same cardinality. One last thing: For any cardinality you have a Hilbertspace with an ONB of that cardinality.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich my understanding is that the question is: Does every Hilbert space have a countable orthonormal basis?

Comment: In the book I am reading it is not specified wether the orthonormal sets in the theorems are countable or not and I was a bit confused whether the arguments applied in the uncountable case but I see now that the proof holds if we assume that the basis is uncountable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $S$ be a set of any cardinality, and consider $L^2(S,\delta)$, where $\delta$ is counting measure on $S$. For $s\in S$, let $e_s$ be the function that is $1$ at $s$ and $0$ otherwise. Each $\delta_s$ is a unit vector in $L^2(S,\delta)$, and $\langle e_s,e_s'\rangle=\delta_{s,s'}$. So $\{ e_s \}_{s\in S}$ is an orthonormal subset of $L^2(S,\delta)$. In fact, it is an orthonormal basis. Any other orthonormal basis of $L^2(S,\delta)$ must have the same cardinality as $\{ e_s \}_{s\in S}$. $L^2(S,\delta)$ is a Hilbert space, and all orthonormal bases of a Hilbert space must have the same cardinality, which means there is no countable orthonormal basis for $L^2(S,\delta)$ unless $S$ is countable.